# How to open the git cloned project into sublime 2?

Tags: git, macos, github, sublimetext2

I have git cloned a project using git clone "url" and now I wish to look the files inside it. How am I supposed to open that project i sublime2 using mac terminal?

Answer (score 0):

`git clone` will just download the contents of the git repo locally. To open it, just open it like any other file or folder. This can be done via open in sublime or using the terminal by something like `sublime2 .` in the downloaded directory (assuming `sublime2` is the sublime executable or a script to launch it).

Comment: I get that now! Thanks. Is there a way to open the subime from the terminal, using a command?

Comment: if there a folder named "Fol1" and i would like to open this folder in sublime2 using a mac command. Is it possible?

Comment: You should be able to replace the dot with a file or folder name to open it. To open it with a terminal, something that opens sublime will need to be in your `PATH`. This can be a script to open it or (my preference) a symbolic link to the executable. I haven't used sublime in a while, but it's possible that sublime adds a link of something like `sublime` or `sublime2` in your `PATH`. See [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/41586/134929).

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text 2 ships with a CLI called **subl**

Enter this into the Terminal;

```
open /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl
```

and if it opens Sublime, you're all set.

[Read more here](https://gist.github.com/artero/1236170), this is how I set my workflow up.

Comment: Thanks that helped!